# Biblatex: add prefix to citations

Tags: biblatex

I would like the entries in the bibliographies to be prefixed in the text and the bibliographies such that they are of the form [A1], [B1] und [C1].

I read the documentation of [biblatex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and found section 3.7.10.
Also, I found the official biblatex example [file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/94-labelprefix.tex), which seems to be what I need.
However, I do not want to adapt the bib file and in this example, they are using keywords.

Actually, I have a document at hand using multibib for this problem and now I would like to use biblatex but this will not be accepted if it is more difficult for the coauthors.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@article{knuth1977fast,
  title={Fast pattern matching in strings},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Morris Jr, J.H. and Pratt, V.R.},
  journal={SIAM journal on computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={323--350},
  year={1977},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
@inproceedings{knuth1970simple,
  title={Simple word problems in universal algebras},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bendix, P.B.},
  booktitle={Computational problems in abstract algebra},
  volume={263},
  pages={297},
  year={1970}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catC}

\newcommand{\citeA}[1]{\addtocategory{catA}{#1}\cite{#1}}
\newcommand{\citeB}[1]{\addtocategory{catB}{#1}\cite{#1}}
\newcommand{\citeC}[1]{\addtocategory{catC}{#1}\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
See \citeA{knuth1986texbook} and \citeB{knuth1977fast} and \citeC{knuth1970simple,knuth1977fast}.

\printbibliography[title={Category A},category=catA]
\printbibliography[title={Category B},category=catB]
\printbibliography[title={Category C},category=catC]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your categories were disjoint the following would work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catC}

\newcommand*{\AddCiteToCategory}[1]{%
  \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\newcommand{\citeA}{\AddCiteToCategory{catA}\autocite}
\newcommand{\citeB}{\AddCiteToCategory{catB}\autocite}
\newcommand{\citeC}{\AddCiteToCategory{catC}\autocite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
See \citeA{worman} and \citeB{sigfridsson} and \citeC{nussbaum,geer}.

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[title={Category A},category=catA]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[title={Category B},category=catB]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[title={Category C},category=catC]
\end{document}
```

No explicit refcontext assignments would be necessary, since each entry automatically picks up the last refcontext was printed in.

The approach also works if one entries is present in several refcontexts, but an entry will always use the last refcontext it was printed in. So the [B1] citation will become a [C1].

---

In your setting, where it is allowed to have overlapping contexts, but you still want the context of the cite command you are using, we need a more sophisticated approach.

We override the refcontext that `biblatex` would normally get in `\blx@getrefcontext` from the last time an entry was printed by manually pointing to a specific refcontext with `\SetRefcontext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catC}

\makeatletter
% we want to be future proof
\providerobustcmd*{\blx@kv@setkeys}{\setkeys}

% this is basically what \assignrefcontextentries does
% but on a slightly different level
\newrobustcmd*{\SetRefcontext}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\blx@tempa{\blx@sorting}%
  \def\blx@tempb{global}%
  \let\blx@tempc\@empty%
  \def\blx@tempd{global}%
  \def\blx@tempe{global}%
  \blx@kv@setkeys{blx@assignrefcontext}{#1}%
  \blx@edef@refcontext{\blx@tempa/\blx@tempb/\blx@tempc/\blx@tempd/\blx@tempe}%
  \edef\blx@tempa{\endgroup
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\blx@refcontext@context{\blx@refcontext@context}}%
  \blx@tempa}

% hard-set the refcontext
% make sure entries are added to category
\newcommand*{\MultibibCiteHelper}[1]{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \def\blx@getrefcontext##1{%
      \let\blx@refcontext@context@saved\blx@refcontext@context
      \SetRefcontext[labelprefix=#1]}%
    \AtEachCitekey{%
      \addtocategory{cat#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\citeA}{\MultibibCiteHelper{A}\autocite}
\newcommand{\citeB}{\MultibibCiteHelper{B}\autocite}
\newcommand{\citeC}{\MultibibCiteHelper{C}\autocite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
See \citeA{worman} and \citeB{sigfridsson} and \citeC{nussbaum,sigfridsson}.

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[title={Category A},category=catA]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[title={Category B},category=catB]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[title={Category C},category=catC]
\end{document}
```

[image: See [A1] and [B1] and [C2, C1].]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. However, there are things that are still not 100% clear to me.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@article{knuth1977fast,
  title={Fast pattern matching in strings},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Morris Jr, J.H. and Pratt, V.R.},
  journal={SIAM journal on computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={323--350},
  year={1977},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
@inproceedings{knuth1970simple,
  title={Simple word problems in universal algebras},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bendix, P.B.},
  booktitle={Computational problems in abstract algebra},
  volume={263},
  pages={297},
  year={1970}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catC}
\DeclareRefcontext{labelprefix=A}{refcatA}
\DeclareRefcontext{labelprefix=B}{refcatB}
\DeclareRefcontext{labelprefix=C}{refcatC}

\newcommand{\citeA}[1]{%
    \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=A]{refcatA}%
    \assignrefcontextentries[labelprefix=A]{#1}%
    \addtocategory{catA}{#1}%
    \cite{#1}%
    \end{refcontext}%
}
\newcommand{\citeB}[1]{%
    \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=B]{refcatB}%
    \assignrefcontextentries[labelprefix=B]{#1}%
    \addtocategory{catB}{#1}%
    \cite{#1}%
    \end{refcontext}%
}
\newcommand{\citeC}[1]{%
    \begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=C]{refcatC}%
    \assignrefcontextentries[labelprefix=C]{#1}%
    \addtocategory{catC}{#1}%
    \cite{#1}%
    \end{refcontext}%
}

\begin{document}
See \citeA{knuth1986texbook} and \citeB{knuth1977fast} and \citeC{knuth1970simple,knuth1977fast}.
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=A]{refcatA}
\printbibliography[title={Category A},category=catA]
\end{refcontext}
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=B]{refcatB}
\printbibliography[title={Category B},category=catB]
\end{refcontext}
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=C]{refcatC}
\printbibliography[title={Category C},category=catC]
\end{refcontext}


\end{document}
```